# How to specify 2 seperate date ranges in a single filter

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to write an ldap filter which will retrieve the following users:

- in the `person` category
- is of class `user`
- has **not** had their account disabled
- they must have either changed their password:

  - between the last 80-90 days
  - or in the last day

This way, I can see both users whose password is about to expire as well as users who have changed their password today.

I have been able to get the expiring users with this filter

```
$"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(pwdLastSet>={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-80).ToFileTime()})(pwdLastSet<={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90).ToFileTime()})(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
```

But when I try to include users who changed their password today with

```
$"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(&(pwdLastSet>={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-80).ToFileTime()})(pwdLastSet<={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90).ToFileTime()}))(&(pwdLastSet<={DateTime.Today.ToFileTime()})(pwdLastSet>={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToFileTime()})))(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
```

I **ONLY** get users who set their password today.

Can anyone help me by pointing in the right direction or giving general tips for building this type of filter (i.e. specifying 2 date ranges in a single filter)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my filter working and at the same time rearranged the code to make it more readable (I think):

```
private static string objPersonFilter = "objectCategory=person";
private static string classUserFilter = "objectClass=user";
private static string AccountEnabledFilter = "!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2";
private static string pwdExpiringMinimum = $"pwdLastSet<={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-80).ToFileTime()}";
private static string pwdExpiringMaximum = $"pwdLastSet>={DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90).ToFileTime()}";
private static string pwdChangedToday = $"pwdLastSet>={DateTime.Today.ToFileTime()}";

private string expiringPasswordFilter = 
    $"(&({objPersonFilter})({classUserFilter})({AccountEnabledFilter})(|({pwdChangedToday})(&({pwdExpiringMinimum})({pwdExpiringMaximum}))))";
```

Comment: DateTime.Today returns you date in local time. Active Directory stores dates in UTC. Replace DateTime.Today.ToFileTime with DateTime.UtcNow.ToFileTime